# converting python2 to python3 getattribute

Tags: python, python-3.5

My script runs into a recursive loop on Python3, I have tried replacing `iteritems` with `items` but it doesn't fix the issue, Python2 runs fine.. is there some change to `__getattribute__` I am unaware of?

```
class Map(object):    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for arg in args:
            if isinstance(arg, dict):
                for k, v in arg.items():
                    self.__dict__[k] = v
                    self.__dict__['_' + k] = v

        if kwargs:
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                self.__dict__[k] = v
                self.__dict__['_' + k] = v

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        if hasattr(self, 'get_' + attr):
            return object.__getattribute__(self, 'get_' + attr)()
        else:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)

    def get(self, key):
        try:
            return self.__dict__.get('get_' + key)()
        except (AttributeError, TypeError):
            return self.__dict__.get(key)


Map(**{'hello': 'world', 'foo': 'bar'})  # infinite recursion
```

When run, this produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 29, in <module>
    Map(**{'hello': 'world', 'foo': 'bar'})  # recursive loop
  File "demo.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.__dict__[k] = v
  File "demo.py", line 17, in __getattribute__
    if hasattr(self, 'get_' + attr):
  File "demo.py", line 17, in __getattribute__
    if hasattr(self, 'get_' + attr):
[...]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Could you supply some test code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @cdarke it seems hasattr(self, 'get_' + attr): causes the problem in PY3 fixed by using try/except clause with AttributeError instead

Answer (score 0):

You have infinite recursion here because your `__getattribute__` is calling `hasattr()` which [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=hasattr#hasattr) states works by calling `getattr()` (thus calling your class's `__getattribute__`).

You must not call `hasattr()` in your `__getattribute__`.

The [documentation for `__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattribute__#object.__getattribute__) notes this potential for infinite recursion and provides guidance on the solution:

> In order to avoid infinite recursion in this method, its implementation should always call the base class method with the same name to access any attributes it needs, for example, object.**getattribute**(self, name).